# Feature importances in linear model text classification, StandardScaler(with_mean=False) yes or no

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, classification

In a binary text classification with [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) with a [SGDClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) linear model on a TF-IDF representation of a bag-of-words, I want to obtain feature importances per class through the models coefficients. I heard diverging opinions if the columns (features) should be scaled with a [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html)(with_mean=False) or not for this case.

With sparse data, centering of the data before scaling cannot be done anyway (the with_mean=False part). The [TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) by default also L2 row normalizes each instance already. Based on empirical results such as the self-contained example below, it seems the top features per class make intuitively more sense when not using StandardScaler. For example 'nasa' and 'space' are top tokens for sci.space, and 'god' and 'christians' for talk.religion.misc etc.

Am I missing something? Should StandardScaler(with_mean=False) still be used for obtaining feature importances from a linear model coefficients in such NLP cases?

Are these feature importances without StandardScaler(with_mean=False) in cases like this still somehow unreliable from a theoretical point?

```
# load text from web
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups

newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'), 
                                    categories=['sci.space','talk.religion.misc'])
newsgroups_test = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test', remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'), 
                                    categories=['sci.space','talk.religion.misc'])

# setup grid search, optionally use scaling
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

text_clf = Pipeline([
    ('vect', TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2), min_df=2, max_df=0.8)),
    # remove comment below to use scaler
    #('scaler', StandardScaler(with_mean=False)),
    #
    ('clf', SGDClassifier(random_state=0, max_iter=1000))
])

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
parameters = {
    'clf__alpha': (0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0)
}

# find best model
gs_clf = GridSearchCV(text_clf, parameters, cv=8, n_jobs=-1, verbose=-2)
gs_clf.fit(newsgroups_train.data, newsgroups_train.target)

# model performance, very similar with and without scaling
y_predicted = gs_clf.predict(newsgroups_test.data)
from sklearn import metrics
print(metrics.classification_report(newsgroups_test.target, y_predicted))

# use eli5 to get feature importances, corresponds to the coef_ of the model, only top 10 lowest and highest for brevity of this posting
from eli5 import show_weights
show_weights(gs_clf.best_estimator_.named_steps['clf'], vec=gs_clf.best_estimator_.named_steps['vect'], top=(10, 10))    


# Outputs:

No scaling:
Weight?     Feature
+1.872  god
+1.235  objective
+1.194  christians
+1.164  koresh
+1.149  such
+1.147  jesus
+1.131  christian
+1.111  that
+1.065  religion
+1.060  kent
… 10616 more positive …
… 12664 more negative …
-0.922  on
-0.939  it
-0.976  get
-0.977  launch
-0.994  edu
-1.071  at
-1.098  thanks
-1.117  orbit
-1.210  nasa
-2.627  space 

StandardScaler:
Weight?     Feature
+0.040  such
+0.023  compuserve
+0.021  cockroaches
+0.017  how about
+0.016  com
+0.014  figures
+0.014  inquisition
+0.013  time no
+0.012  long time
+0.010  fellowship
… 11244 more positive …
… 14299 more negative …
-0.011  sherzer
-0.011  sherzer methodology
-0.011  methodology
-0.012  update
-0.012  most of
-0.012  message
-0.013  thanks for
-0.013  thanks
-0.028  ironic
-0.032  <BIAS>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have a theoretical basis on this, but scaling features after `TfidfVectorizer()` gets me a little bit nervous since that seems to damage the idf part. My understanding of `TfidfVectorizer()` is that in a sense, it scales across documents and features. I cannot think of any reason to scale if your estimation method with penalization works well without scaling.